# Message not coming fully

Tags: java

I need to get a complete message for example `Hello How are you`. But with this code, I am only getting `Hello`.

```
public class Messages{
    private static final int MTYPE = 0;
    private static final int FLAGS = 1;
    private static final int SEQUENCE = 2;
    private static final int CHAR1 = 3;
    private static final int CHAR2 = 4;
    private static final int CHAR3 = 5;
    private static final int CHAR4 = 6;
    private static final int CHAR5 = 7;

    private int type = 0;
    private boolean ack = false;
    private boolean isLastTelegram = false;
    private boolean isUTF8 = false;
    private int sequence = 0;
    private String messagePart = "";

    public InMsgTelegramm(byte[] msg) {

        type = msg[MTYPE] & 0xFF;

        sequence = msg[SEQUENCE] & 0xFF;

        int ackbyte = (int) ((msg[FLAGS] >> 7) & 1);

        ack = ackbyte != 0;

        int isLastTelegrambyte = (int) ((msg[FLAGS] >> 6) & 1);

        isLastTelegram = isLastTelegrambyte != 0;

        int isUTF8byte = (int) ((msg[FLAGS] >> 5) & 1);

        isUTF8 = isUTF8byte != 0;

        messagePart += (char) msg[CHAR1];
        messagePart += (char) msg[CHAR2];
        messagePart += (char) msg[CHAR3];
        messagePart += (char) msg[CHAR4];
        messagePart += (char) msg[CHAR5];
    }
```

It is the `messagePart` that contains 5 characters say `Hello`. It is not in a loop. `msg`is a byte array that accpets the String `Hello How are you`but finally I get the output as `Hello`

Rest of the parameters except sequence remain the same for the message. How do I get a fully message?

Comment: In the last 5 lines you only read 5 characters. What else do you expect other than the 5 characters of "Hello"?

Comment: You only get five characters from `msg`, how do you expect to get the full message if you only retrieve five characters? You need to create a loop there.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - That is what I am looking for. I dont know how to loop this

Comment: Well, how do you know where the message ends? This depends on your protocol. Do you have any length field? End of message marker? Or are you sure the array length is going to change based on the length of the message?

Comment: I can get the length of the msg and iterate my for loop until the lenght right?

Comment: If that's how the message is defined. If there are other fields after the 8th byte, or if the message is split between several `msg` arrays, then it won't work. Without knowing the definition of the protocol, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Is it possible I can check the messagePart is null and determine as end of message